# Error during the reading of the serial port in VB

Tags: python, vb.net, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I set up a bluetooth connection between Raspberry and a computer. I wish to carry out a pilot icon which would allow me to check if connection is always present. For that I carried out a Thread. For the test, I sending a message on the link of the PC towards RPi, if the Rpi receive something , she reference me a message and if I receive it on my computer is that the connection is always present. The probelm is that I have an error at the time of the reception side PC.

Here the detail: The operation of E/S was  abort because of the stop of a thread or the request of an application.

Here two  codes for the connection series:

Pc side with VB :

```
Private Sub checkBT()
    Dim buffer As String = ""

    While True
        BluetoothPort.Write("Test")
        buffer = BluetoothPort.ReadLine()
        While buffer = ""
            buffer = BluetoothPort.ReadLine()
        End While
        WriteInLog("" & buffer)
        checkBT_thread.Sleep(20000)
    End While
End Sub
```

Rpi side with Python:

```
import serial

serial_com = serial.Serial("/dev/rfcomm0", baudrate = 115200, timeout = 0, writeTimeout = 5)
print "INIT Bluetooth connection"

while 1:
    x = serial_com.readline()
    if x == "Test":
         print x
         serial_com.write("Recu")
```

Do you have an idea about the problem please?
Can the error come owing to the fact that I use of Windows forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the serialPort.ReadExisting() method.